# partykit::ctree randomness in majority=TRUE

Tags: r, party

I am trying to understand how ctree fits/predict observations with complete missingness in all predictors. For example,

```
library(partykit)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airq <- rbind(airq,data.frame(Ozone=rnorm(50),Solar.R=NA,Wind=NA,Temp=NA,Month=NA,Day=NA))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq,control = ctree_control(majority = TRUE))
table(tail(predict(airct,type="node"),50))
```

The last 50 rows of `airq` are missing all predictors, and from reading the documentation, I get the impressions that with `majority=TRUE` it will just follow the majority, meaning they should all go into the same node with no variation at all. And yet I get a distribution of prediction for them.

So

1. is my understanding of how `majority=TRUE` works correct?
2. How is ctree fitting/predicting the rows that doesn't have any observed predictors?

by the way, I tried tracing the code to see how the `majority` argument is used and see that line `#104` in `partykit:::.cnode` has:

```
prob <- numeric(0) + 1L:length(prob) %in% which.max(prob)
```

which look rather strange to me as the result will always be `numeric(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is/was a bug in the handling of the `majority` control argument. It had recently been fixed in the R-Forge repository (see https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=261) but not yet been released to CRAN. After running

```
install.packages("partykit", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

everything should work as expected. A date for the CRAN release has not yet been scheduled but should not be in the too distant future, I think.